# Green's function in 3+1D Minkowski spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, waves, greens-functions, propagator

What's **the Green's function of d'Alembert operator in 4D Minkowski spacetime**? I mean the solution to the equation
$$
\Box G \equiv \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2 G = \delta^{4}(x)~?
$$

---

I've had some thoughts about this question.

If it was in Euclidean space, the 4D Green's function is (the source point set to be the origin)
$$
G(\boldsymbol x,0)=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{r^2},
$$
where $r$ is the distance from field point $\boldsymbol x$ to the source point $0$:
$$
r^2 = \boldsymbol x^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{4}(x^i)^2.
$$
It's easy to show that $$\nabla^2 \left(-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{r^2}\right) = 0$$ at any point other than the origin point. And we can integrate it over a spherical volume centered at  the origin point:
$$
\int \nabla^2\left(-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{r^2}\right) \mathrm d^4x = \int \nabla \left(-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{r^2}\right) \cdot \mathrm d\boldsymbol S = 1.
$$

A natural analogy in Minkowski spacetime would be
$$
G(x,0) = -\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{t^2-\boldsymbol x^2},
$$
where $\boldsymbol x$ here represents spatial part of $x$. Actually, this expression appears in Problem 6.1 of Matthew Schwartz's QFT textbook.

I have verified that $$\Box \left(-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=0$$ as long as $x$ is not the origin point. But I can't verify the $\delta$-funcion part. I can't do the integral as in Euclidean space because the function always diverge on the light cone $t^2-\boldsymbol x^2=0$. No matter how the integral ball is, there will always be many points in the ball making the funciton ill.

---

Is the function above the correct Green's function? How to demonstrate that the correct Green's function can give a $\delta$-function?

Comment: It seems that the Feynman propagator is the Green's function of d'Alembert operator and it's easy to verify it in the momentum space. But as far as I know, there's some converging problem with Feynman propagator?

Comment: Maybe the Feynman propagator is enough, since finally we'll always multiply the Green's function by some other function and integrate them? Then I don't need to worry integrating the Green's function alone in a ball.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the Green's function unique,
you need to specify a boundary condition.

For the boundary condition $\lim_{t\to -\infty}G(\mathbf{x},t)=0$
(which is probably the most often used one) the solution is
$$G(\mathbf{x},t)=\frac{1}{4\pi r}\Theta(t)\delta(t-r)$$
where $\Theta$ is Heaviside's step function.
See also [d'Alembert operator - Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator#Green%27s_function).

For other boundary conditions you will get other Green's functions.